# Eclipse can't see content in CVS Repository

Tags: eclipse, synchronization, repository, cvs

I'm trying to check out files from our CVS Repository (I have access, but I don't have repository admin access), but I'm running into an issue where certain sub-folders of the module in question aren't displaying their contents, and they are failing to do so consistently. That is, certain folders *do* display their contents, while others do not.

Does anyone who has Eclipse usage experience know why this might be happening? My team members do not have this issue.

**Update: My team members, since uninstalling and reinstalling their versions of Eclipse, are now experiencing the issue.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is a big difference between using the Repository View's 'Check Out As..' command and using the "New Project..." command from the 'File' menu. The former works, and the latter does not.

Answer (score 0):

in cvs repository view,right-click--->select the branch you want to import your eclipse,then select the project name--->check out as,and you get the project files into your eclipse workspace.